# Проблема импорта sexpdata при запуске скрипта python

Tags: python, macos, homebrew

Я столкнулся со следующей проблемой: клонировал с git репозиторий dpsprep https://github.com/kcroker/dpsprep, там указано, что необходимо установить модуль sexpdata, который уже у меня установлен, но несмотря на это, при запуске скрипта выдаётся ошибка ImportError: No module named sexpdata и я совершенно не понимаю что с этим делать. ОС macos big sur

Answer (score 0):

Оказывается, установка пакетов через homebrew не предполагает установку в системный питон, установив этот модуль в систему, проблема решилась.